# Caching by varyByParam WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

i have a method which is not a wcf operation, that does the authentication checks

how can i cache its results for like 60 sec? and used the cached results if exits on my operation methods and if it doesn't exists execute the method to get the result?

i want to cache this method based on user name and password.

```
public Autenticate (UserAccount useacc)
{
............
}  


 public class UserAccount
{
string username, passsword, domainname;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFCache.aspx) for caching.

And you can use the class as follows.

```
WCFCache.Current.Insert(username, useacc, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
//get an item from the cache
user = (UserAccount )WCFCache.Current[username];
```